# Substring command not working in solaris kshell

Tags: unix, awk, solaris, substr

I am trying to use the following command to extract a substring from a string :

```
propertyPath=$(echo $path|awk '{print substr($0,3,$index)}')
```

However the command does not pick up the value of the `$index` variable and therefore does not return a valid substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
propertyPath=$(echo $path|awk '{print substr($0,3,'$index')}')
```

or

```
propertyPath=$(echo $path|awk -v index=$index '{print substr($0,3,index)}')
```

Answer (score 1):

propertyPath=$(echo $path|awk "{print substr(\$0,1,$index)}")

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes tell the shell not to expand values, so you'll have to use double quotes around your awk command.  When you do that though, you'll have to escape the $ for the variables you do not want to expand early.

Comment: is this what you roughly mean ? 
propertyPath=$(echo $path|awk "{print substr(/$0,3,$index)}")